# Implementing a right-hand-size CSS flyout nav menu

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with implementation of a CSS flyout nav menu. I'd like the menu to be hidden behind the page and revealed on button click (Facebook-style).

I've managed to make it work where the nav menu slides together with the page:
http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/N5vZ5/

But I can't figure out how to make the nav menu to be *fixed* in place. Obviously, if I change its positioning to `fixed` and put it lower with `z-index` the nav menu links no longer work:
http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/N5vZ5/1/

Any ideas how can I make the links work in the latter example?

Comment: Where is this menu supposed to be **fixed**?

Comment: The nav menu should be fixed in place = not moving. So when the page slides to the left to reveal the nav menu, the navigation is **not** moving with it (my first fiddle) but is fixed in position (my second fiddle). Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the nav isn't clickable is because of its negative z-index putting it underneath the body of the page. You'd logically expect then, that something like this should work:

```
.page {z-index: 1;}
nav {z-index: 0;}
```

However, because `nav` is a child of `.page`, it inherits the parent's index and can never be positioned 'underneath' it. ([Read more about that here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index))

The best way to work around this is to take `nav` out of those containing elements altogether and applying those index values, separating it from any element who it's going to compare its `z-index` with.

Rather than rework all of your code, [I've put together a similar example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/ymp4L/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but isn't your example exactly like my first? I try to make nav menu **not** sliding but fixed in place.

Comment: Wow, sorry. I guess I completely glossed over that and now feel a bit stupid! I'll edit in a working example of a fix, but unfortunately it will require a slight reworking of your code.